# How to create a new <li> with a checkbox or <a> in it?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a web site, and I have an input board where the user types a message, then it appears in an `ul` list. When I write something in the input board and publish the text, the text appears in the `ul` list, but if I want to delete the post, I would need an anchor or a checkbox, but how do I do that?

`$('<li>').addClass("valgt").text(post).prependTo('.Melding')`; <--- Here I would like to add an anchor or a checkbox, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$('<li>').append('<input type="checkbox" />Checkbox description ');
```